# Example for Dedekind complete spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

A real vector space $E$ is said to be an ordered vector space whenever it is equipped with an order relation $≥$ that is compatible with the algebraic structure of $E$.
A Riesz space is an ordered vector space E which for each pair of vectors $x,y∈E$, the supremum and the infimum of the st ${x,y}$ both exist in $E$. An example of Riesz space is function space $E$ of real valued functions on a set $Ω$ such that for each pair $f,g∈E$ the functions $[f∨g](w):=\max\{f(w),g(w)\}$, $[f∧g](w):=\min\{f(w),g(w)\}$ both belong to $E$.

A Riesz space is caled Dedekind complete whenever every nonempty bounded above subset has a supremum.

Are $L^p[0,1]$ spaces Dedekind complete?

Comment: Bounded set in the sense that there exists an $f$ with $f≥g$ for all $g$ in the set? In this case you may use something like Beppo Levi or Fatou to see that $L^p$ spaces have this propetry. (As a remark, the relation $f≤g$ has to mean $f(x)≤g(x)$  for _almost all $x$_)

Comment: In the case  $f≤g$ iff $f(x)≤g(x)$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$; let $A \subset L^1[0,1]$ and there existes $g \in L^1[0,1]$ such that for any $f \in A$ we have $f \leq g$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$. Now let $A$ is uncountable and $u_f$ is the set that for all $x \in u_f$ we have $f(x) > g(x)$. For any $f \in A$ the measure of $u_f$ is equal to zero. But is the measure of $\cup_{f \in A}u_{f}$ is (necessary) equal to zero?  Beppo Levi or Fatou Lemma are can only be used in the case where $َA$ is countable.

Comment: I see, countability of the set is necessary so that the supremum over it remains measurable. At any rate this gives you counter-examples for any $p$. Let $V$ be some non-measurable set in $[0,1]$ and let $A=\{ f\in L^2[0,1] \mid f(x) ≤ \chi_V(x) \text{ almost everywhere }\}$. This set is bounded by the constant function $1$, but the only possibility for a supremum is $\chi_V$, which is not measurable and hence not in $L^p$.

Comment: Countability of the set is sufficient so that the supremum over it remains measurable. Let $B=\{ f∈L^2[0,1] ∣ 0 \leq f(x) ≤ \sin(x)~ almost~everywhere \}$. $B$ is not countable but we have $\sup B = \sin(x)$  and $g(x) = \sin(x)$ is measurable. By the way, I didn't understand why $χ_V$ is the only possibility supremum for $A$.